# C# port of Apache POI corrupts embedded OLE objects in .xlsx

Tags: c#, excel, apache-poi, npoi

I'm working on a program that processes .xlsx workbooks and reformats them to match a style guide. And on the first sheet of these documents there is an embedded OLE object (a word document) that details aspects of the files.

Whenever I save back my workbook the object gets corrupted, even if skip the first sheet when I execute my processing.

My load and save back code is as follows:

```
FileStream fStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
IWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fStream);
fStream.Close();

//do stuff

fStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
wb.Write(fStream);
fStream.Close();
```

The documentation falls short on answering my questions, and previously asked SO questions have remained unanswered so I'm guessing this is either quite a complicated problem or a ridiculously stupid mistake either way I hope you guys can be of assistance.